# Trouble activating account on carthagenet

Tags: docker, faucet, carthagenet

I'm playing around with carthagenet, but I'm having trouble activating an account with the .json file I got from https://faucet.tzalpha.net/

I'm using the docker script for carthagenet and I'm trying to activate an account with:

`./carthagenet.sh client -A rpctest.tzbeta.net -P 443 -S activate account bob with "container:xxxXXXXXxxxxx.json"`

but I get the error:

`Error: Invalid activation. The public key xxxXXXXXxxxxx does not match any commitment.`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Even though I'm still getting that error, when I run a `get balance` I can see that the activation worked and my account has tez